# importing non-root components

Tags: javascript, svelte

I have a svelte component library with a structure like this

```
lib
└ index.js [1]
  └ components
    └ index.js [2]
    └ Badge.svelte

[1]
export * as component from "./component";

[2]
export { default as Badge } from "./Badge.svelte";
```

this sort of works. But when trying to use the `Badge` component I have to import it in a rather funky way that I would like to get rid of

```
<script>
    import { component } from 'style';
    const Badge = component.Badge;
</script>

<Badge count="4" color="green">new words</Badge>
```

And I wonder, is it possible to do the same, but without the `const Badge = component.Badge;` line?

Answer (score 1):

If in [1] you export like this:

```
[1]
export * from "./component";
```

You'll be able to import like this:

```
import { Badge } from './lib';
```